# Additional object for a ConcurrentBag?

Tags: c#, linq

What is the meaning of this code snippet:

```
ConcurrentBag<UserModel> _userStore;

public Task UpdateUser(UserModel userModel) <br>
{ 
   _userStore = new ConcurrentBag<UserModel>(_userStore.Where(u => u.Email != userModel.Email)); 
   return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

What does the statement { `usermodel` }?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This initializes the ConcurrentBag with one item.

It is equivalent to:

```
_userStore = new ConcurrentBag(_userStore.Where(u => u.Email != userModel.Email));
_userStore.Add(userModel);
```